# How to add data to attachment dialog box of a form using VBA?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to add an attachment that is found within the current database to a control on the current form:

I have a form that contains both a combo box ("cmb") and an attachment control ("attachctrl").
The user shall be able to choose a value in the combo box and the corresponding attachment shall be added to the attachment control.
I am using an SQL query to get the recordset from the table containing the attachments. I am able to get some data (e.g. the file name, type, URL and the data).

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim intResult As Integer
Dim strSQL As String
Dim existingEntry

Set db = CurrentDb
strSQL = "SELECT [Analysis1] FROM [tblAnalysis] WHERE [ID] = '" & Me.cmb.Value & "'"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
```

I can then access the fields within the recordset as:

```
fileName = rs(0).Value.fileName 
fileType = rs(0).Value.FileType 
fileData = rs(0).Value.FileData
```

However, how can I add the data to the corresponding fields of the attachment control?
When I try to manually write the data to the fields I get an error message, that I am not allowed to write to the field in question:

```
Me.attachctrl.fileName = rs(0).Value.fileName 'not working
Me.attachctrl.FileType = rs(0).Value.fileName 'not working
Me.attachctrl.FileURL = rs(0).Value.FileURL 'not working
```

Also: I can't find a field that would take the actual data of the attachment. Where do I assign the data to?

Comment: They are not widely used, but I guess they are meant to be used as bound controls. Try googling for "ms-access attachment control unbound" if you need it unbound.

Comment: I don't think an attachment control can work that way. Must be associated with a table field.  Use combobox selection to apply filter criteria to a form or report that will display record containing the desired attachment.

Comment: Are these image files (jpg, png, bmp) in attachment field? An option is to use an unbound Image control to pull image from attachment field. DLookup() expression in ControlSource can dynamically pull image from attachment field, assuming attachment field stores only one file.